# Unexpected Results with Functional Programming in C

Tags: c, haskell, functional-programming, purely-functional

While experimenting functional style in C programming, I tried to translate the following Haskell code to C.

```
f (0, 0, 0, 1) = 0
f (0, 0, 1, 0) = f (0, 0, 0, 1) + 1
f (0, 1, 0, 0) = f (0, 0, 1, 1) + 1
f (1, 0, 0, 0) = f (0, 1, 1, 1) + 1
f (a, b, c, d) = (p + q + r + s) / (a + b + c + d)
    where
    p
        | a > 0 = a * f (a - 1, b + 1, c + 1, d + 1)
        | otherwise = 0
    q
        | b > 0 = b * f (a, b - 1, c + 1, d + 1)
        | otherwise = 0
    r
        | c > 0 = c * f (a, b, c - 1, d + 1)
        | otherwise = 0
    s
        | d > 0 = d * f (a, b, c, d - 1)
        | otherwise = 0

main = print (f (1, 1, 1, 1))
```

to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define int const int
#define double const double

double f(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d == 1)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 1 && d == 0)
    {
        return f(0, 0, 0, 1) + 1.0;
    }
    else if (a == 0 && b == 1 && c == 0 && d == 0)
    {
        return f(0, 0, 1, 1) + 1.0;
    }
    else if (a == 1 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d == 0)
    {
        return f(0, 1, 1, 1) + 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        int p = a > 0 ? a * f(a - 1, b + 1, c + 1, d + 1) : 0;
        int q = b > 0 ? b * f(a, b - 1, c + 1, d + 1) : 0;
        int r = c > 0 ? c * f(a, b, c - 1, d + 1) : 0;
        int s = d > 0 ? d * f(a, b, c, d - 1) : 0;
        return (double)(p + q + r + s) / (double)(a + b + c + d);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", f(1, 1, 1, 1));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I expected the exact same behaviour, but the C program always output 0.0. With `f(0, 0, 1, 1)` they both output 0.5, but whenever the number gets a litter bigger, the C version simply doesn't work. What is going wrong?

Comment: I think you need to declare a,b,c,d and p,q,r,s as `double` too in the C version. Then you can also omit the cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int p = a > 0 ? a * f(a - 1, b + 1, c + 1, d + 1) : 0;
int q = b > 0 ? b * f(a, b - 1, c + 1, d + 1) : 0;
int r = c > 0 ? c * f(a, b, c - 1, d + 1) : 0;
int s = d > 0 ? d * f(a, b, c, d - 1) : 0;
```

Here the results of the recursive calls to `f` are truncated to an integer when they are stored in the int variables. So, for example, if `a` is 1 and `f(a-1, b+1, c+1, c+1)` is `0.5`, `p` will be 0 instead of `0.5` because you can't store `0.5` in an int.

In the Haskell code all variables are doubles (or rather fractionals), so you should do the same in your C version and declare all variables and parameters as `double`.

Comment: I think parameters should be left as `int`s, otherwise comparisons to `0` and `1` won't work.

Comment: @AntonSavin They're doubles in Haskell, so to be equivalent they should be doubles in C, too. Also none of the operations done on the arguments would make the comparisons to 1 and 0 inaccurate unless I'm missing something.